# Optimizing a query with CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql

MY query looks something like this:

```
select cat1, cat3, cat4
       sum(case when cat2='x' then val end) as sumValForX,
       sum(case when cat2='y' then val end) as sumValForY
from your_table WHERE date between somedate and someotherdate AND mainname=somename
group by cat1, cat3, cat4
```

Basically this groups my table on cat1,3,4; and shows a cumulative total on the resultant groups *separately* for when cat2='x' and cat2='y'.

I'm working on a very large table (say 5 million records) so this is taking a lot of time of course. It's workable, but I just wanted to ask some of the MySQL pros here on what sort of optimizations I can do to my table to make this quicker.

What would be the best technique to use here to make

1. Group by faster
2. The WHERE faster (indexing? partitioning?)
3. The CASE WHEN faster (which I think is the main slowdown).

Some insight about the data:

In around 5mil records,

`mainname` is the column with most repeated values. So maybe 1mil for 5 types of `mainname`.

Within those 1mil, I have a range of around ~90 dates spread out on which I'm executing the BETWEEN statement.

Also within those 1mil each, there are MAX 4-5 distinct `cat2`. So there might be 'x', 'y' or maybe 'z' 'z1' too, but not more. I have additional sum(case when... statements corresponding to the number of types of `cat2`s.

To put it differently, I need the grouped sum for each type of `cat2`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked at an explain plan for your query?

Comment: You can consider adding the condition `AND cat2 in ('x', 'y')` to limit the data that you are working with. Also, you can consider a slightly different output with `select cat1, cat3, cat4, cat2, count(*) Val
from your_table WHERE date between somedate and someotherdate AND mainname=somename AND cat2 in ('x', 'y')
group by cat1, cat3, cat4, cat2`.

Answer (score 1):

The `CASE` expressions are unlikely to cause much of a "slowdown". You could test that by removing those expressions from the SELECT list.)

A suitable **covering index** is likely your best bet for improving performance of this query.

In my experience, with queries like this on large sets, the **`GROUP BY`** is the biggest slowdown. I know that with InnoDB and a suitable covering index, I am sometimes able to eliminate the "Using filesort" operation (as shown in the EXPLAIN output.) MySQL can optimize the GROUP BY operation using an index with appropriate leading columns, rather than a "Using filesort" operation. The range predicate (in the WHERE clause) on the `date` column might be a problem, and interfere with that.

We'd need to run `EXPLAIN` to verify.

Based on the query, I'd suggest a covering index:

```
... ON your_table (mainname, cat1, cat3, cat4, date, cat2)
```

The `mainname` column first (because of the equality predicate in the `WHERE` clause, MySQL can make use of an index range scan).

Next the three columns in the `GROUP BY` clause (to optimize the GROUP BY operation).

Followed by the additional columns referenced in the query (to make this a "covering" index, with no need to reference the pages in the underlying table.)

We'd hope to see "Using index" in the EXPLAIN output, and no "Using temporary" and no "Using filesort".

(I'm assuming here that the references to `somedate`, `someotherdate` and `somename` are references to literal values supplied in the statement, not column references.)

---

If the the number of rows returned is very small (compared to the size of the table), then you could try creating an index with `maindate` as the leading column, followed by the `date` column, and then the other columns in any order. With that index, MySQL could do a range scan on the `date` column, but then would need to do a "filesort" operation to perform the GROUP BY.

You could try adding an `ORDER BY NULL`, if the order the rows are returned in is not important. I've not seen any performance boost with that, but the documentation suggests that optimizations may be possible (in a more recent or future release, perhaps?)

---

For a large set, my instinct would be to go with getting the `GROUP BY` optimized.

---

If I couldn't get a good execution plan (the predicate on the `date` column might be a problem), I'd explore the option of re-writing the statement to relocate that predicate into the CASE expression:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN t.date BETWEEN 'foo' AND 'bar' AND t.cat2 = 'x' THEN t.val END)
```

Note that this has a potential to change the resultset, by returning `(cat1,cat3,cat4)` values that do not appear within the specified date range. If that was a problem, I could probably monkey up a `HAVING` clause that would eliminate those "extra" rows.

If portability wasn't a concern, I'd probably opt for an equivalent MySQL `IF()` expression

```
SUM(IF(t.date BETWEEN 'foo' AND 'bar' AND t.cat2 = 'x', t.val, NULL))
```

(but that's unlikely to have any change performance.)

Comment: `date` should be before `cat1` in the index, unless there is reason to believe that MySQL will use the index for the `group by`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: yes, exactly. **If** MySQL doesn't use the index for the `GROUP BY` (With InnoDB, I've seen MySQL use an index for the GROUP BY), **then** the `date` column should be second. We want the  column with the equality predicate first column, and the column with the range predicate second. If that predicate on the `date` column interferes with MySQL using the index to optimize the GROUP BY, I'd consider moving that into the conditionals in the SELECT list.

Comment: About the covering index you mentioned `... ON your_table (mainname, cat1, cat3, cat4, date, cat2)`; I should say that the order of the columns in `group by` can be changed, and even the number, according to user requirement. So is it wise to index it in such a way since it would only benefit a fixed order of columns? Btw, `EXPLAIN` says `Using where; Using filesort` (there's an index on `mainname`)

Comment: @user1265125: I believe the optimizer is "smart enough" to recognize that `GROUP BY b,c,a` can use an index `ON (a,b,c)` to optimize that, though the result would then need to be sorted; for testing, we can add an `ORDER BY NULL` to suppress the sort required by the implied `ORDER BY b,c,a`. MySQL can use the same index to optimize a GROUP BY on a subset of the _leading_ columns in the index, e.g. `GROUP BY a,b`. But that index couldn't be used to optimize `GROUP BY c` (without equality predicates on `a` and `b`).

Comment: @user1265125: If there are a large number of permutations of the `GROUP BY`, and it's impractical to provide indexes MySQL can use to optimize the `GROUP BY` (i.e. unable to avoid the "Using filesort" operation on a large set), then your next best bet is an index with leading columns of `(mainname,date)` to optimize the `WHERE`, to quickly locate the set of rows that need to be sorted.